# GCC 10.0.1 accepts header name with characters that are not in the basic source character set

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

i am currently reading the C++ standard reference (C++ 17).
I read the following about header names:

> 5.8 Header names
>
> header-name:
>     < h-char-sequence >
>     " q-char-sequence "
> h-char-sequence:
>     h-char
>     h-char-sequence h-char
> h-char:
>     any member of the source character set except new-line and >
> q-char-sequence:
>     q-char
>     q-char-sequence q-char
> q-char:
>     any member of the source character set except new-line and "

The source character set consists out of these characters:

> 5.3 Character sets
>
> The basic source character set consists of 96 characters:
> the space character, the control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab,
> form feed, and new-line, plus the following 91 graphical characters:
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> _ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ~ ! = , \ " '

I created a file called header³.h
I tried the following in a cpp file and it compiled without an error:

```
#include "header³.h"
```

I compiled this with a GCC Version 10.0.1 Compiler.

So right now i wonder myself why this compiled.
Is there something i overlooked or misunderstood?

Comment: gcc implements many things that are not specified in the C or C++ standard. This is obviously one of them. gcc doesn't really care what is the name of each source file is. C or C++ code in a file of one particular name is just as good as the same C or C++ code in a file with some different name.

Comment: I would guess most compilers would be fine with any name that is valid on the filesystem.

Comment: According to [this identifier reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) there's plenty of Unicode characters allowed. Are you sure that specific character isn't in one of the allowed sets? Have you tried to build with strict standard compliance (without GCC-specific extensions)? How do you build your [mcve]?

Comment: I will try to turn off the GCC-specific extensions. Didn't thought about that. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Not to mention that the compiler ["searches for the file in **implementation-defined** manner"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) (emphasis mine).

Comment: Your quotes from the standard say what a compiler *must* support. Do you have any quotes saying that those are the *only* characters that *can* be supported? What does the standard say should happen if a character other than those is used?

Answer (score 0):

gcc's behavior does not violate the standard.

The characters between `""` or `<>` in a `#include` directives are members of the *source character set*. The *basic source character set* is limited to the 96 characters you listed. The *source character set* may include additional implementation-defined characters.

In a quick look at the C++ standard, I couldn't find a very clear statement of this, but does use the phrases "basic source character set" and "source character set" in different contexts, so it's at least reasonable to assume they're not necessarily the same. The C standard is more explicit; see [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.2.1 paragraph 1).)

And even if it did violate the standard, gcc/g++ is not conforming by default, and in particular it does not issue all required diagnostics. To compile in conforming mode, you can use

```
g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic
```

or

```
g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic-errors
```